# Terrible performance spikes updating AWS S3 files from Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, performance, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am calling S3.putObject from inside a JavaScript Lambda updating small JSON files 2->10K.
Usual performance is OK  - typically well under 100ms. However I get occasional worrying spikes of 10-20 seconds. I have had a few spikes in the range of minutes. The worst so far is 587 seconds!!.

Has anyone ever seen anything similar?

Looks like the problem is not specific to S3 - but caused by network glitches and that the default SDK Http timeout is set to 120 secs. The fix is to set maxRetries and httpOptions as shown below.

```
import aws from "aws-sdk";
aws.config.logger = console;
const config = { 
  maxRetries: 5, 
  httpOptions: { timeout: 4 * 1000, connectTimeout: 2 * 1000 } 
};
const S3 = new aws.S3(config);
```

Also note setting the logger causes time and retries to be written to Cloudwatch log.

Comment: How are you measuring this? The duration of a given Lambda invocation?

Comment: Logging around the call to S3.putObject(). Do Date.now() before and after call, and console log the difference. Then filter Cloudwatch logs.

Comment: Just a thought- if you’re updating 10k files in quick succession you could be hitting the rate limit of 1k objects per second. The extra latency could come from retries if you don’t see failures. 

If that’s what’s happening, there’s a way to fix it...Use different prefixes for your JSON S3 objects. Each prefix goes to a different partition ideally and each partition has its own rate limit. 

Hopefully I’m not wrong. :)